AddHandler in VBA script (not Excel, not MS Access)
Here's my code:
Dim dmis_app As Object
Dim dmis_part_program As Object
Dim dmis_Machines As Object

Sub main()
    Set dmis_app = CreateObject("PCDLRN.Application")
    Set dmis_part_program = dmis_app.ActivePartProgram
    Set dmis_Machines = dmis_app.Machines
    
    If (dmis_Machines.Count > 0) THEN
        dmis_Machine = dmis_Machines(0)
    EndIf
    
    ​AddHandler dmis_Machine.ErrorMsg addressOf HandleErrorMessage
End Sub

Sub HandleErrorMessage(string msg, int msgNum)
    MsgBox "Ding Dong!"
End Sub

How do I go about adding an event handler in generic VBA? (Meaning that I don't have any using statements, and every object is dimensioned as Object, as shown above. Everywhere I look on the internet, the only thing I see is Excel VBA, but that's not what I'm after. This is going to be a .bas script.)

AddHandler and Using are both from VB.NET. VBA is a different language and does not have them. "A .bas script" is going to be VBScript (as opposed to "generic VBA"), which is also a different language from VB.NET or VBA, and it does not have AddHandler either. Irrespective to that, this code is not valid VBScript, as VBScript does not have data types (As Object etc). It would not be valid in any VB variety either (string msg, int msgNum etc).

@GSerg can you explain why you insist on the tag [vbscript] instead of [VBA] for this question? It explicitly asks for a solution in VBA, the sample code is definitely not VBScript, and .bas file extensions are usually used when saving VBA code. I understand that the solution might be to use VBScript instead, but the question seems to be purely about VBA.

@GeertBellekens Because to the best of my judgement the OP has confused VBA and VBScript. They meant to create a stand-alone script file executable outside of the Office environment. The sample code is definitely not VBScript, but definitely not VBA either. "Generic VBA" is what the OP seems to erroneously call VBScript. I guess it is theoretically possible that the goal was to create a "shared library" VBA .bas file to be imported into one Office application or another, but all things considered about this question, it seems highly unlikely. I would also need to revoke the close vote then.
